# Which comparison methods are used by the built-in max function?

Tags: python

`sorted` requires only `__lt__` to be defined on the sorted iterable's contents. This is technically enough to calculate a maximum but `sorted[-1]` is slightly less efficient than the `max` function and I'd rather just use that, but I can't figure out what a minimal custom comparison implementation looks like.

Which methods does `max` require?

P.S. assume for some reason I cannot use the `total_ordering` decorator to bypass the issue altogether.

Comment: I believe that's implementation-dependent, in CPython just `__gt__` but you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering to ensure all comparisons are covered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand why this is a question. Did you **try it**? What happens if you try using `max` on a sequence of objects that don't implement any comparison methods, e.g. `max((object(), object()))`? What happens if you try implementing the method mentioned in the error message? It seems like you aren't at all a beginner, so what part of this exactly are you finding difficult?

Comment: "sorted[-1] is slightly less efficient" - well of course. I would argue that it is *a lot less* efficient. 1) It creates a new object the full size of the old one; 2) it takes O(nlogn) while a simple min/max takes O(n). It's an order of magnitude worse than a simple min/max in both time and space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You will need any or both of `__lt__` and `__gt__` depending on the case. In the general case (number 2 below) you will need *both*.

1. If you are doing a `max()` over an homogeneous collection (all the items are of the same class), or an heterogeneous collection where you have control over the definition of all the involved classes, then it does not matter. Either `__lt__` or `__gt__` is enough: regardless of the one you implement, any comparison of the form `a < b` will always be able to be evaluated using either `a.__lt__(b)` or `b.__gt__(a)`, and any comparison of the form `a > b` will always be able to be evaluated using either `a.__gt__(b)` or `b.__lt__(a)`. So if either one of the two methods is defined for both classes the comparison will always work.
2. If instead your collection is not homogeneous and you do not have control over all the classes in the collection, you will need both. This is because `a < b` cannot be computed if `a` does not implement `__lt__` for the class of `b` or vice-versa `b` does not implement `__gt__` for the class of `a` (same reasoning goes for `a > b`). Suppose you cannot control `b`'s class definition, then you cannot control whether `b` implements `__lt__` or `__gt__` for an instance of `a` (it most likely does not, e.g. if `b` is a simple `int`). Since you cannot know in which order the internal comparisons would happen (you also don't know the order of the items in the collection in general), you cannot guarantee that only implementing one of the two methods is enough.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Having either of `__lt__` or `__gt__` defined between all items is fine.

---

The `max`, `min` and similar functions use the [builtin equivalent of the `<` or `>` operators](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/50b9a7762f06335277d9962edc8d39498601a4e4/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1796). Notably, these operators do not correspond directly to their special method – rather, `a < b` will try `a.__lt__(b)` first *and fall back to `b.__gt__(a)`if needed*.

> #### [Data model: `object.__lt__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)
>
> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s reflection […]

---

While the use of operators for `max`/`min` is not strictly specified, they generally fall under the umbrella of sorting operations. Various official sources guarantee the use of the `<` operator as opposed to directly using special methods.

> ##### [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)
>
> The sort algorithm uses only `<` comparisons between items.

> ##### [Sorting HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends)
>
> The sort routines use `<` when making comparisons between two objects. [...], note that `<` can fall back to using `__gt__()` if `__lt__()` is not implemented

Comment: *"Either of `__lt__` or `__gt__` is fine."* - false. This is only true if `a` and `b` are instances of the same class or both `a` and `b` implement the same method for each other's classes. `1 < a` will fail if `a` does not implement `__gt__`. `1 > a` will fail if `a` does not implement `__lt__`. So in general, you need both.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I think it is obvious that either of these methods has to be defined and apply to the entire content. Of course things can still fail even if the methods *exist* – even if it's just because they raise an error. Enumerating all the possible gotchas of implementing operators doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. I might be getting deeper than needed into the analysis of the situation.